# Xcode Jump To Bookmark or Breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Like a lot of programmers I am often moving back and forth throughout a large file. Commonly I am working on a method, I then have to move to the top of the file and then want to go back to that method quickly.

Is there a way to 'bookmark' a certain line in Xcode so that with one shortcut I can quickly return to that section. Possibly this could be by creating a breakpoint, then the question would be is there a shortcut to move focus to the next available breakpoint in the file?

Hope this is possible as would make for a much more productive workflow.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a shortcut for exactly what you want, but there are two shortcuts that I use a lot in cases like this:

- Ctrl + 6, then type a the first few characters of the method I want to jump to.
- Ctrl + Cmd + (Back Arrow || Forward Arrow), jump back and forth between changes/files you have been making.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I was hoping for something more direct. The ctrl+6 is certainly close to what I want, but would really like a single shortcut to go straight back to the method, without having to type any of the name

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 15 onwards, you can finally do that. Just go to the function you want to bookmark and with the alternative button of your mouse you can now bookmark a specific code line or an entire code file.

Your bookmarks will show up in the new tab on top of the navigation pane of Xcode main window as in here:

[image]